# Change SugarCRM ListView Pagination

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm trying to update the pagination for the SugarCRM ListView. Using the IDE search tool I found that it is done in:

`include/ListView/ListViewPagination.tpl`

If I need to implement a new pagination design, what would be the best way to edit the above template file? How can I override the template file?. If overriding is the way to go about it, please tell me where and how it can be done.

By the way, I'm using *SugarCRM Community Edition 6.5.10*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in an upgrade-safe manner. You can't simply copy `include/ListView/ListViewPagination.tpl` to the `custom/` directory, make changes there and have them reflect. If it's more of a cosmetic change you could however override the CSS.